# Collection Framework basic query

Tags: java

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

This is giving me an error

> `ArrayList<String>` cannot be converted to `List<Object>`

Comment: Change `Object` to `String` or `String` to `Object`.

Answer (score 1):

You can add any object to a `List<Object>`, but you should only be able to add `String` objects to a `List<String>`. Therefore you cannot assign a `List<String>` to a `List<Object>` variable.

If your `List` should only hold `String` objects, change its type :

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```